# Feed sql query output to a new sql in a "for-each" style

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to do a nested query and I am having a bit of trouble. I have two tables (simplified for this question) with Player information, and another with team information. My ultimate goal is to find players that are on more than one team, and then Print out what team they are on.

I've created a [sqlfiddle for testing](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/367b6/18) using MS SQL Server 2014. Here is a small pictorial representation of my problem (note that I have omitted the last Team from this test set in my database initialization code):

**[EDIT:] sqlfiddle site is having some issues so I've attached my DB initialization code**
**[EDIT2:]sqlfiddle is up again**

```
 CREATE TABLE Players (
  userid int NOT NULL,
  name char(10) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT [PK_Players] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([userid]),
  );
  
 INSERT INTO Players (userid,name) VALUES
 (0,'Tim'),
 (1,'John'),
 (2,'Amy'),
 (3,'Stacy'),
 (4,'Craig'),
 (5,'Adam'),
 (6,'Rachael'),
 (7,'Steve'),
 (8,'Mitch');
 
 CREATE TABLE Teams (
   teamid int,
   team_name char(10),
   player0 int,
   player1 int,
   player2 int,
   player3 int
   CONSTRAINT [PK_Teams] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([teamid]),
   -- Says that each of the Player# must correspond to a userid in the Players Table
   CONSTRAINT [p0_2_player_tbl] FOREIGN KEY ([player0]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Players] ([userid]),
   CONSTRAINT [p1_2_player_tbl] FOREIGN KEY ([player1]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Players] ([userid]),
   CONSTRAINT [p2_2_player_tbl] FOREIGN KEY ([player2]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Players] ([userid]),
   CONSTRAINT [p3_2_player_tbl] FOREIGN KEY ([player3]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Players] ([userid]),
   );
   
INSERT INTO Teams(teamid, team_name, player0,player1,player2,player3) VALUES
(0,'green',0,1,2,3),
(1,'red'  ,4,2,5,0),
(2,'blue' ,6,7,8,2),
-- (3,'black',2,2,2,NULL);
```

[image]

So far I've managed to find all the players on multiple teams

```
-- this portion in parenthesis Finds all the players on multiple teams
SELECT userid,name,count(*) as 'Num Occurances'
FROM Players
INNER JOIN Teams 
   ON player0=Players.Userid 
   OR player1=Players.Userid 
   OR player2=Players.Userid 
   OR player3=Players.Userid 
GROUP BY userid,name
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

[image: find duplicates result]

I've also wrote sample code to fidn out which team the player belongs to. As you can see I've explicitly searched for `userid = 0`

```
/*I think I want to take the userids returned, and fnd what team 
they are on*/
SELECT teamid,team_name
FROM Teams
WHERE 
     Player0=0 -- Instead of typing the ID directly
  OR Player1=0 -- I'd like to get it from the 
  OR Player2=0 -- previous query
  OR Player3=0
;
```

[image: resolve names to teams]

Ultimately my goal is to do a nested query where the output from my first query of players on multiple teams will be the input to my teamid lookup query. I've developed this so far, but it isn't working exactly how I'd like it to

```
/*Issues combining the two statements, I'm not sure how to do this
 I made this attempt, but It's not quite right, it list every team
 and the two players, (thing of oring Player0=0 OR Player0=2
 I want a list of each player and the teams they belong to*/
SELECT name,team_name
FROM Players,Teams
WHERE userid IN (
-- this portion in parenthesis Finds all the players on multiple teams
SELECT userid -- ,name,count(*) as 'Num Occurances'
FROM Players
INNER JOIN Teams 
   ON player0=Players.Userid 
   OR player1=Players.Userid 
   OR player2=Players.Userid 
   OR player3=Players.Userid 
GROUP BY userid,name
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)  GROUP BY name,team_name
ORDER BY name ASC;
```

However this is giving me **every** team with **any** duplicates (think of doing Player0=0 OR player0=2) as seen below in red

[image: current incorrect sql output]

What I want is something similar to a "for each" style loop. Where we search for the teams of **EACH** player returned from the previous query rather than a search for the team of **ANY** player returned form the previous query. You can see my goal output below (in green)

[image: desired SQL ouput]

Comment: Look into "Common Table Expressions" or CTEs.

Comment: The biggest key to working effectively with SQL is to switch from a procedural mindset to a set-based mindset. Don't think of how you can work through the data to get your results. Think of how you can combine your sets of data (tables) to get the results you want in as few passes as possible. Most flavors of SQL can do some pretty nifty things with data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Count teams per user with `COUNT OVER`. Then keep those records for which the count is greater than one.

```
SELECT userid, user_name, teamid, team_name
FROM
(
  SELECT 
    p.userid,
    p.name AS user_name,
    t.teamid,
    t.team_name,
    COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY p.userid) AS num_teams
  FROM Players p
  JOIN Teams t ON p.Userid IN (t.player0, t.player1, t.player2, t.player3)
) counted
WHERE num_teams > 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

SQL always offers a variety of possible solutions, but I'll try my hand at providing one here.

Your inner query should simply fetch the players that are on multiple teams (which you've already done), and the outer query can just join those results back to the "Teams" table.

```
SELECT name, team_name FROM (
    SELECT userid, name 
    FROM Players
    INNER JOIN Teams ON 
        Players.userid IN (player0, player1, player2, player3)
    GROUP BY userid, name
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) a
INNER JOIN Teams ON userid IN (player0, player1, player2, player3)
ORDER BY Name ASC
```

---

Note: I've modified this...

```
player0=Players.Userid 
OR player1=Players.Userid 
OR player2=Players.Userid 
OR player3=Players.Userid
```

...to this...

```
Players.Userid IN (player0, player1, player2, player3)
```

...just for a bit cleaner of a query.

Comment: Thanks for the very quick help, this is a great solution. As you said one of many, I'm very grateful, +1